# The number of characters increases when I send it to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I write program in which I send data of document to a DOCUMENT table in Oracle.
the col in table are: id, name, url (of doc/picture), owner.
The NAME col is define to VARCHAR2(20), and actually I send less than 20 char,
but disappointingly the response from the server is:

> ORA-12899: value too large for column (actual: 58, maximum: 20).

I don't know what cause the num of char to incerase in the name of document.
I would be happy to hear any suggestion.

I check the data that arrive to the server (.Net) and is exactly what I sent in the client (Angular).

Here is my code in the server side:

```cs
namespace DrawingApp.Controllers.docsControllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CreateDocCtrl : ControllerBase
    {
        ICreateDocService _service;
        public CreateDocCtrl(ICreateDocService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public Response CreateDoc([FromBody] CreateDocsRequest request)
        {
            return _service.createDoc(request);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace DocumentsService
{
    [Register(Policy.Transient, typeof(ICreateDocService))]
    public class CreateDocService : ICreateDocService
    {
        IDocsDal _dal;
        public CreateDocService(IDocsDal dal)
        {
            _dal = dal;
        }
        public Response createDoc(CreateDocsRequest request)
        {
            Response retval = null;
            try
            {
                _dal.CreateDoc(request);
                //check if doc created:
                var newDoc = _dal.GetDoc(request.DocData.DocId).Tables[0].Rows;
                if (newDoc.Count == 1)
                {
                    retval = new CreateDocResponseOk("Document was created!");
                }           
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retval = new CreateDocResponseErr(ex.Message);
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public DataSet CreateDoc(CreateDocsRequest request)
{
    IDBParameter p_owner = _dalInfra.getParameter("Owner", OracleDbType.Varchar2, request.DocData.Owner);
    IDBParameter p_docId = _dalInfra.getParameter("DocId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, request.DocData.DocId);
    IDBParameter p_docUrl = _dalInfra.getParameter("DocUrl", OracleDbType.Varchar2, request.DocData.DocUrl);
    IDBParameter p_docName = _dalInfra.getParameter("DocName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, request.DocData.DocName);
    return _dalInfra.ExecuteSPQuery(_conn, "CREATE_DOC", p_owner, p_docId, p_docUrl, p_docName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR2(20)` means 20 bytes not 20 characters

`1 byte` not equals always to `1 char`(e.g. non-English characters).

Try to update you db varchar2 type byte  to char or  increase byte to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what was the problem,
when I sent the params to its Stroe Prodedure CREATE_DOC,
I switched between the position of parameter docUrl (that was 58 length) and the position of docName:

```
 return _dalInfra.ExecuteSPQuery(_conn, "CREATE_DOC", p_owner, p_docId, p_docUrl, p_docName);
```

while in the sql developer the order was oposite:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CREATE_DOC
(
      P_OWNER IN VARCHAR2 
    , P_DOCID IN VARCHAR2 
    , P_DOCNAME IN VARCHAR2 
    , P_DOCURL IN VARCHAR2
```

After the change don't forget Rebuild your project!